# Integrating existing widget into React/Redux based Web app

Tags: reactjs, redux

As a dumb UI developer I can't solve system of linear equations to draw [trend line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trend_line_(technical_analysis)). I will use some UI library or plugin (like d3.js).

So React/Redux based Web app will have foreign widgets (for SVG, tables, Canvas) on the page to reduce cost of project.

Which React/Redux API allows passing data to/from foreign widget?

What event/data movement lifecycle should I implement?

Answer (score 1):

Specific to d3, there are wrapper libraries already available, ie http://www.reactd3.org/components/

Otherwise, you'd do the same as any other component - pass props down from your store, and dispatch events to change state. If you need more control over the input / output and a higher level abstraction, I'd wrap your foreign widget functionality in a component suited to your needs. It's all JavaScript ;)